# Refresh fragment listview on Activity back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment which contains a listview of some items. On click of an item in the list view an Activity is started to view the details about the list view. There is a back button on the Activity which brings us back to the fragment page. Once the back button is pressed and the activity page closes I want the data to be refreshed in the fragment list view. I have tried onResume() method but it does not refresh the data.

Can someone please help me how to achieve this am pretty new at this.

```
public class FavCommittee extends Fragment {
    public ArrayList<Committee> favCommitteeData = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        final SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFav", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        View rootView =getView();
        Map<String,?> entries = pref.getAll();
        final Set<String> keys = entries.keySet();
        int count=0;
        for (String key:keys) {
            String val = pref.getString(key, null);
            String[] store = val.split(":");
            if (store[0].equals("committee"))
                count=count+1;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<keys.size();i++) {
            String val = pref.getString(Integer.toString(i), null);
            if (val != null) {
                String[] store = val.split(":");
                if (store[0].equals("committee")) {
                    count = count - 1;
                    new GetAllCommittees(getContext(), rootView).execute(store[1], Integer.toString(count));
                }
            }
        }        final ListView yourListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.house_listview);
        yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Committee obj = (Committee)yourListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FavCommittee.this.getActivity(), committee_info.class);
                intent.putExtra("Committee",obj.getCommittee_id());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.house, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: put code of fragment

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha added

Comment: did you override onBackpress on navigation as home click in activity? i got onResume after onBackpress and on Navigation clicked

Comment: Currently I am doing this:-public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    } How can I change it

Comment: your code for onBackPress is okay written in comment hence you should get onResume of fragment, if still it doesn't work try startActivityforResult(intent, code), refresh your view onActivityResult();

Comment: @Anirban:- You have a model class Committee, 
1 - Add an Interface in that model class,
2 - Create a setListener(yourInterface object),
3 - Then create a getter and setter method with boolean variable, which will notify change of state,
4 - And at last implement that listener in your fragment and Committee.getInstance().setListener(this) in yourActivityCreated method in your fragment.
5 - Now when you find boolean value changed, call your service and you'll get your updated list... That's it

Answer (score 0):

When you are transitioning between Fragments, call addToBackStack() as part of your FragmentTransaction:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransation();
tx.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag").commit();
```

If you require more detailed control (i.e. when some Fragments are visible, you want to suppress the back key) you can set an OnKeyListener on the parent view of your fragment:

//You need to add the following line for this solution to work,

```
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
fragment.getView().requestFocus();
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
@Override
public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
} );
```

Comment: its not between two fragments...its between a fragment and an activity

Answer (score 0):

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragContainer, new FavCommittee (), FavCommittee .class.getName()).commit();

Try this code.
Put the code where u add your Fragment in Activity

Comment: I dont add fragment from activity...i add activity in fragment

Comment: ohk can you show me your code where  Adding Activity in Fragment ?

Comment: that is your Activity

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(FavCommittee.this.getActivity(), committee_info.class);
                intent.putExtra("Committee",obj.getCommittee_id());
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: ohk and where you fill the Listview ?

Comment: yourListView.setAdapter()?

Comment: you want code for that...i have that in my fragment